# Problem with Steam after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, games, steam

I have been using Ubuntu since version 12.04 LTS but only got into playing games on Linux with Steam recently.  I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and upon attempting to run Steam I get the following (rather unhelpful) error message:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-08-05 17:01:08] Startup - updater built Jul  8 2016 21:43:51
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get the error just after starting Steam? Or when launching a game? Can you run Steam on a terminal and post the output?

Comment: The text in the middle of the original post was the terminal output when I called steam.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of searching I found a workaround for the issue I was experiencing. Apparently there is an issue with the video drivers that are included with the steam distribution and Ubuntu past version 14.xx.

The workaround was to delete the following files from the steam directory:

```
~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

Doing so forces steam to use the drivers that the OS is using instead of the open source drivers they include.

The link that got me this information is https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3820.